# Real Analysis - Cluster Point

Tags: real-analysis, limits

Determine a condition on $\left | x-1 \right |$ that will assure that $\left | x^2-1 \right |< \frac{1}{2}$

Answer (score 2):

$|x^2-1|<1/2~\iff~ 1/2<x^2<3/2~\iff~-\sqrt{\frac{3}{2}}<x<-\sqrt{\frac{1}{2}}~\text{or}~\sqrt{\frac{1}{2}}<x<\sqrt{\frac{3}{2}}$

Answer (score 1):

hint: $$|x^2-1|=|x-1|\cdot |x+1|$$

Answer (score 1):

If $x$ is close to $1$ or to $-1$, then $x^2$ will be close to $1$; we need to make this precise. For a number close to $1$, the "worst-case scenario" is when it is a bit greater than $1$. To see this, consider the factorization $x^2-1=(x-1)(x+1)$. When $(x-1)$ is small, $(x+1)$ can still be somewhat large, especially when $x>1$. For example, we might naïvely choose $x$ in the interval $[\frac14,\frac54]$, but that won't work, because $(\frac54-1)(\frac54+1)$ the second factor being greater than $2$.

One way to solve this problem is to choose $x$ in the interval $[\frac56,\frac76]$, because we're not in danger of $x+1$ being greater than $3$. If you want an open interval, use $(\frac56,\frac76)$. Of course, the reflection of this interval, $(-\frac76,-\frac56)$ also works.

If this solution seems insufficiently precise, check out the other answer posted here, but usually for this type of problem, you only need a sufficient condition, not a necessary one.

Comment: ok. thanks for your answer